# Problems compiling peazip on OSX

Tags: macos, compression, zip, compilation, pascal

I'm having some problems with compiling [Peazip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/) on OSX (10.6). I emailed the Peazip developer and he said he probably couldn't help me too much as the error seems to be OSX specific and he doesn't have access to an OSX machine any more.

The compiler I'm using is [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_(software)) as the source is in Pascal.

The actual compile process seems to go ok, but when I run the peazip.app program launcher, I get the following error: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v215/thegooddale/Screen-shot-2010-05-22-at-71907-PM.png

Here is the app launcher that the compile made: http://forboden.com/coding/peazip.app.zip   -  you can use an unzip program to look at the files inside (i.e. unzip it twice).

I also tried just running the peazip unix file executable that was produced after the compile from the terminal and I got this: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v215/thegooddale/Screen-shot-2010-05-22-at-72148-PM.png

Here are the messages from the compile log from Lazarus while compiling Peazip: http://pastebin.com/qK4bdncL

(I asked on the Lazarus forums and they said I can just ignore those "ld: warning: unknown stabs type" warnings).

Here is the info from the project_peach.compiled file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CONFIG>
  <Compiler Value="/usr/local/bin/ppc386" Date="1238949773"/>
  <Params Value=" -MObjFPC -Sgi -O1 -gl  -k-framework -kCarbon -k-framework -kOpenGL -k'-dylib_file' -k'/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib' -WG -vewnhi -l -Fu/Users/yansky/Desktop/peazip-3.1.src/res/themes/crystalc/ -Fu/Developer/lazarus/components/synedit/units/i386-darwin/ -Fu/Developer/lazarus/ideintf/units/i386-darwin/ -Fu/Developer/lazarus/lcl/units/i386-darwin/ -Fu/Developer/lazarus/lcl/units/i386-darwin/carbon/ -Fu/Developer/lazarus/packager/units/i386-darwin/ -Fu/Users/yansky/Desktop/peazip-3.1.src/ -Fu. -opeazip -dLCL -dLCLcarbon project_peach.lpr"/>
</CONFIG>
```

I guess there's little chance that anyone here has experience with Pascal and Lazarus since it's not that popular a language and the compiler is still in beta, but I thought I would post here in the hopes that someone might point me in the right general direction about where/how the peazip.app launcher is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC somewhere inside the bundle a symlink must be made.